# Add cdata tags to xml docuemnt

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-xml

I want to replace all my xml attributes with cdata tags, eg:

```
<Title> test </Title>
<ID> 3939 </ID>
```

Has cdata tags within them.

What would be a qucik way to do this?

Comment: How about showing what the expected output you'd like is? But since you're doing DOM manipulations, you'd use a DOM library.

Comment: Those aren't attributes.  Why on earth do you want to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont know how you are reading/writing your XML document 
but `XmlWriter` class has a `.WriteCData(string)` method to be used in the content of a tag.

It's not possible to write CData on an attribute.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [XCData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xcdata%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)  construct from the Linq-to-XML Library, which should automaticly wrap a CData tag around a string.

Example:

```
//Assuming your string is called @string

XCData cdata = new XCData(@string);

string cdataString = cdata.ToString();
```